# Add fadeOut in front of fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this script to filter elemets based on class. Currently it stops previous function and fade in new class.

Basically i need to fadeOut everything before it starts to fadein selector. Currently it is a sharp cut from 100% opacity to starting fadeing in selector, and i want to smoothly fade out current (or specific class) and after that fade in this one.

**my Code:**

```js
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=radio]', 'change', update);
    update();
    function update() {
        var $lis = $('.results > div'),
            $checked = $('input:checked');
        if ($checked.length) {
            var selector = $checked.map(function () {
                return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
            }).get().join('');
    
            $lis.hide().filter(selector).stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');
    
        } else {
            $lis.stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
       <label class="odseba">
        <input class="fadeout" type="radio" checked="checked" rel="all" name="gg" /><span>VŠETKO</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="web" name="gg" /><span>WEB</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="eshop" name="gg" /><span>ESHOP</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="seo" name="gg" /><span>SEO</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="grafika" name="gg" /><span>GRAFIKA</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="logo" name="gg" /><span>LOGO</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="reklama" name="gg" /><span>REKLAMA</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="kampan" name="gg" /><span>KAMPAŇ</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="branding" name="gg" /><span>BRANDING</span></label>
       <label class="odseba">
        <input type="radio" rel="print" name="gg" /><span>PRINT</span></label>
        </div>

and these are idems being filtered:

    <div class="span4 thumb-pad0 all web eshop print seo">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <figure><a href="img/img5.jpg"><img src="img/page3_pic5.jpg" alt=""></a></figure>
            <div class="caption">
                <h2 style="font:28px/28px 'Century Gothic', 'Century Gothic', Arial, Helvetica, Century Gothic; color:#FFF; text-transform:uppercase; margin:0;">Name</h2>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the fadeIn() as a callback to the fadeOut():

```
} else {
    $("elements-to-fade-out").fadeOut(1000, "easeInCirc", function() {
        $lis.stop().fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');
    });
}
```

You could also do:

```
} else {
    $("elements-to-fade-out").fadeOut(1000, "easeInCirc");

    // Fade in after 1000
    //
    setTimeout(function() {
        $lis.stop().fadeIn(1000, "easeInCirc");
    }, 1000);
}
```

See here for info on the callback:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp
```

Comment: Obviously you need to change the selector for the fadeOut() to whatever element(s) you want to apply the fade to. Also, "easing" isn't an actual option...just a placeholder, I dunno what you want, specifically.

But as for passing a callback routine, it should work if you make the correct/necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

Fade out all elements and then use the [callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-easing-complete) function to fade the specific element in:

```
$lis.fadeOut(1000, 'easeInCirc', function(){
   $(this).filter(selector).fadeIn(1000, 'easeInCirc');
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0wkJGOgK3hxIfLX3RqKF?p=info